# Cloud data Point of Sale Software

Tags: open-source

Does anyone know of good open source point of sale software that is cloud based?  Would like the cash register to be hooked to computer, cash drawer, and printer, however the data would be saved in the cloud and this would allow someone at a different terminal to access it and run reports.